# Выводятся посты не только из 10 категории

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php
                $args = array('cat=10','posts_per_page' => 2 );
                $pc = new WP_Query($args); //категории постов которые нужно вывести?>
                <?php if (have_posts()) : $count = 0; ?>
                    <?php while ($pc->have_posts()) : $pc->the_post();$count++; ?>
                        <div class="news__post  <?php if ($count % 2 == 0 ) echo 'container'; ?>">
                            <div class="news__img ">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="news__text">
                                <p class="news__number">
                                <h2><?php echo  $count;?>.</span></h2>
                                </p>
                                <p class="news__date">
                                    <i class="icon-clock"></i>Date:<?php the_date(); ?>
                                </p>
                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><p class="news__caption">
                                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                                    </p></a>
                                <p class="news__preview">
                                    <?php the_excerpt();?>
                                </p>
                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="news__button"><span>read</span> more <i class="icon-right"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Параметры WP_Query задаются ассоциативным массивом ( 'key' => 'value'). Исправьте строку создания параметров:

```
$args = array( 'cat' => 10, 'posts_per_page' => 2 );
```